# Analyze store instruction consisting inttoptr in LLVM

Tags: c++11, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to analyze a byte code consisting of a store instruction with **inttoptr**. I am having trouble to detect whether a store instruction has the **inttoptr** value as the value operand (3rd instruction in the following code in entry BB). My opcode looks like the following:

```
define dso_local i32 @test(i32* %p) #0 {
entry:
  %p.addr = alloca i32*, align 8
  store i32* %p, i32** %p.addr, align 8
  store i32* inttoptr (i64 1000 to i32*), i32** %p.addr, align 8
  %0 = load i32*, i32** %p.addr, align 8
  %1 = load i32, i32* %0, align 4
  ret i32 %1
}
```

I am trying to analyze the store instruction and trying to find whether **inttoptr** is in a store instruction by using **classof** method and with **dyn_cast** like the following code:

```
  StoreInst *store = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(I);
  Value *vv = store->getValueOperand();
  Value *vp = store->getPointerOperand();
  if(IntToPtrInst::classof(vv)){
    outs() << "Inttoptr found\n";
  }
  if(Instruction *inp = dyn_cast<IntToPtrInst>(vv)){
    outs() << "Inttoptr found\n";
  }
```

It seems I am not being able to detect **inttoptr** with any of the methods. I know the byte code is not creating a separate instruction for the **inttoptr** but it is merging with the store instruction. It would be really nice if anyone points me what I am missing and how I can detect the **inttoptr** in a store instruction.

Answer (score 2):

The cast you're interested in is not an instruction, but rather [a constant cast from the constant integer 1000 to a pointer](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html#a02560cda155aaed54314383bed827d60). You can detect it using a test like `isa<ConstantExpr>(foo->getPointerOperand()) && cast<ConstantExpr>(foo->getPointerOperand())->getOpcode() == ConstantExpr::IntToPtrCast`, but I typed that from memory and I'm sure there are typos.

When you read IR, instructions are always on their own line, while constants are inline as arguments or initialisers, even the quite complex constants produced using [ConstantExpr](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html).